# How to get the domain name/IP name in web-API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How can I get the (ipName:PortNumber) mentioned in the below IP address in web-API?

```
https://**ipName:PortNumber**/ProductController/{productId}
```

We have diff servers such as: 000.00.000:8080 (ipname:portnumber), 111.11.111:8181.

I want to load these dynamically into a string as shown below.

```
string webServiceUrl = "https://"+ IP name +"Product Controller/{product Id}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your URI in a string, you can get the information you want as follows:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://example.com:1234/ProductController/7");
string host = uri.Host; // "example.com"
int port = uri.Port; // 1234
```

Inside of an `ApiController`, you can get the current request's URI as `Request.RequestUri`.

If you want to construct a URI given the host and port, you can simply do something lightweight like this:

```
string uri = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}/ProductController/7", host, port);
```

Or something a little more robust like use the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: `Uri.Authority` would be a better choice, as it handles default ports for you.

Comment: @user3629247 You'll have to explain yourself better then. People need to know what you *want* to answer your question - not what you *don't want*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I access the Request object within a Web Api...

```
if (Request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
{
     var ip = (HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
     var host = ((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.Url.Host;
     var port = ((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.Url.Port;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer was a better fit for our needs (since we had no idea what out uri was.)